# How to Cythonize / allow numba.jit on a simple function: (Finding Triangles in network)

Tags: python, cython, numba, cythonize, networkit

**Backstory:**

I have been searching for a highly performant way to find cliques within a network which are below a given dimension (e.g all k-cliques with k<=3 are all nodes, edges, and triangles).  As this example of low dimensional cliques (k<=3 or k<=4) is often the case, I have resorted to simply looking for highly performant triangle finding methods.

Networkx is incredibly slow; however, networkit has a much more performant solution with a Cython backend.

Unfortunately, networkit does not have an algorithm for listing all cliques <= a given dimension.  They have a MaximalCliques algorithm, which is different, and unfortunately simply runs for *all possible dimensions of cliques* in no particular order (from what I can tell).  It also only *counts* triangles, but does not list the nodes which make up each triangle.  Thus, I am writing my own function that implements a reasonably efficient method right now below.

**Problem:**

I have the function `nk_triangles` below; however, it is resisting an easy jamming into numba or Cython.  Therefore, I wanted to see if anyone has more expertise in these areas that may be able to shove this towards faster speeds.

I have made a simple, yet fully workable snippet of code with the function of interest here:

```
import networkit as nk
import numba
from itertools import combinations
from urllib.request import urlopen
import tempfile

graph_url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/networkit/networkit/master/input/tiny_02.graph"
big_graph_url="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/networkit/networkit/master/input/caidaRouterLevel.graph"
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    with urlopen(graph_url) as r:
        f.write(r.read())
    f.read()
    G = nk.readGraph(f.name, nk.Format.METIS)

#@numba.jit
def nk_triangles(g):
    # Source:
    # https://cs.stanford.edu/~rishig/courses/ref/l1.pdf
    triangles = set()
    for node in g.iterNodes():
        ndeg = g.degree(node)

        neighbors = [neigh for neigh in g.iterNeighbors(node)
                     if (ndeg < g.degree(neigh)) or
                        ((ndeg == g.degree(neigh))
                          and node < neigh)]

        node_triangles = set({(node, *c): max(g.weight(u,v)
                                              for u,v in combinations([node,*c], 2))
                              for c in combinations(neighbors, 2)
                              if g.hasEdge(*c)})
        triangles = triangles.union(node_triangles)
    return triangles


tris = nk_triangles(G)
tris
```

The `big_graph_url` can be switched in to see if the algorithm is actually performing reasonably well. (My graphs are orders of magnitude larger than this still)

As it stands, this takes ~40 minutes minutes to compute my machine (single threaded python loops calling C backend code in networkit and itertools). The number of triangles in the big network is 455,062.

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but have you looked at the igraph library? Don't know how it compares to networkit, but definitely faster than networkx. They have python bindings, and the C version at least seems to have a [function](https://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Cliques.html#igraph_cliques) which might be helpful.

Comment: What stops you from just writing the function in Cython with type declarations?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a numpy version of your code taking ~1 min for your big graph.

```
graph_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/networkit/networkit/master/input/tiny_02.graph"
big_graph_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/networkit/networkit/master/input/caidaRouterLevel.graph"

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    with urlopen(big_graph_url) as r:
        f.write(r.read())
    f.read()
    G = nk.readGraph(f.name, nk.Format.METIS)

nodes = np.array(tuple(G.iterNodes()))
adjacency_matrix = nk.algebraic.adjacencyMatrix(G, matrixType='sparse').astype('bool')
degrees = np.sum(adjacency_matrix, axis=0)
degrees = np.array(degrees).reshape(-1)



def get_triangles(node, neighbors):
    buffer = neighbors[np.argwhere(triangle_condition(*np.meshgrid(neighbors, neighbors)))]
    triangles = np.empty((buffer.shape[0], buffer.shape[1]+1), dtype='int')
    triangles[:,0] = node
    triangles[:,1:] = buffer
    return triangles

def triangle_condition(v,w):
    upper = np.tri(*v.shape,-1,dtype='bool').T
    upper[np.where(upper)] = adjacency_matrix[v[upper],w[upper]]
    return upper

def nk_triangles():
    triangles = list()
    for node in nodes:
        ndeg = degrees[node]
        neighbors = nodes[adjacency_matrix[node].toarray().reshape(-1)]
        neighbor_degs = degrees[neighbors]
        neighbors = neighbors[(ndeg < neighbor_degs) | ((ndeg == neighbor_degs) & (node < neighbors))]
        if len(neighbors) >= 2:
            triangles.append(get_triangles(node, neighbors))
    return triangles

tris = np.concatenate(nk_triangles())
print('triangles:', len(tris))
```

Giving me

```
triangles: 455062
CPU times: user 50.6 s, sys: 375 ms, total: 51 s
Wall time: 52 s
```